# unit testing a tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter, python-unittest

Someone can suggest how you can make simple tests here.
This is a simple keyboard trainer on tkinter, a window appears where you can select the difficulty level and start the game.

Or if you can give a link to a resource with explanations

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
from random import choices
root = Tk()  # Создаем основное окно
top = Toplevel()  # Создаем окно для выбора сложности
# добавляем виджеты в окно выбора сложности
var = IntVar()
Radiobutton(top, text='Легкая', variable=var, value=0).pack()
Radiobutton(top, text='Нормальная', variable=var, value=1).pack()
Radiobutton(top, text='Сложная', variable=var, value=2).pack()
button1 = Button(top, text="Играть", command=lambda: command()).pack()
button2 = Button(top, text="Выйти", command=lambda: command2()).pack()
def command():
    global test_words1
    if var.get() == 0:
        with open("words.txt", "r") as words:
            test_words1 = choices(list(words), k=1)
            dif()


    elif var.get() == 1:
        with open("words.txt", "r") as words:
            test_words1 = choices(list(words), k=2)
            dif()

    elif var.get() == 2:
        with open("words.txt", "r") as words:
            test_words1 = choices(list(words), k=3)
            dif()

pos = 0
b = 0
mistakes = 0
correct_presses = 0


def key_type(e):
    if e.keycode != 16:
        global pos, text_widget, b, mistakes, correct_presses
        if (test_text[pos] != e.char):
            text_widget.tag_add("wrong", str(1) + "." + str(b))
            mistakes += 1
        if (test_text[pos] == e.char):
            text_widget.tag_add("correct", str(1) + "." + str(b))
            correct_presses += 1
        b += 1
        pos += 1
        if (pos == len(test_text)):
            end_time = time.time()
            rav=end_time-start_time

            label1 = Label(root2,text="NICE!", fg="#eee", bg="#957")
            label1.pack()

            label2 = Label(root2, text="TIME:", fg="#eee", bg="#957")
            label2.pack()

            label0 = Label(root2,text=rav, fg="#eee", bg="#957")
            label0.pack()
def dif():
    root.withdraw()
    top.destroy()  # Уничтожаем окно выбора сложност
    global root2
    root2 = Tk()  # Создаем основное окно
    root2.deiconify()  # Показываем основное окно
    top.destroy()  # Уничтожаем окно выбора сложности
    global start_time
    start_time = time.time()
    global test_text
    global text_widget

    len_word_list = [len(word.strip()) for word in test_words1]

    index_nostrip1 = 6
    end_of_line1 = 0
    final_word_list1 = []
    lines_list1 = []
    line1 = ""

    for i in range(len(test_words1)):
        if end_of_line1 == index_nostrip1 - 1:
            final_word_list1.append(test_words1[i])
            line1 += test_words1[i].strip()
            lines_list1.append(line1)
            line1 = ""
            end_of_line1 = 0
        else:
            final_word_list1.append(test_words1[i].strip())
            line1 += f"{test_words1[i].strip()} "
            end_of_line1 += 1

        # create the final string to be used in the test
        test_text = " ".join(final_word_list1)

    text_widget = Text(root2, height=10, width=100,
                           padx=20, pady=20, font=("Arial ", 16))
    text_widget.insert(END, test_text)
    text_widget.configure(state="disabled")
    text_widget.tag_config("correct", background="green", foreground="white")
    text_widget.tag_config("wrong", background="red", foreground="white")

    text_widget.bind("<KeyPress>", key_type)
    text_widget.focus()
    text_widget.pack()

    message = Label(root,
                    text="Start typing",
                    font=("Arial ", 24))
    message.pack()
    root2.mainloop()


# эта команда выполняется по кнопке Выйти
def command2():
    top.destroy()  # Уничтожаем окно выбора сложности
    root.destroy()  # Уничтожаем основное окно
    sys.exit()  # Выходим из программы
root.withdraw()  # Скрываем основное окно, пока показываем окно выбора сложности
root.mainloop()
```

*I have already tried to write something similar, but the tests do not pass*

```
class TKinterTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.root=tkinter.Tk()
        self.pump_events()

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.root:
            self.root.destroy()
            self.pump_events()

    def pump_events(self):
        while self.root.mainloop(_tkinter.ALL_EVENTS | _tkinter.DONT_WAIT):
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Why are you using `.dooneevent()`? Why not use `.mainloop()`? This is the first time I see someone using `.dooneevent(...)`. Also have you checked what `.dooneevent(...)` returns (for me it's 0 so the while loop will exit immediately)?

Comment: @TheLizzard I used mainloop, but the tests still fail

Comment: Instead of `while self.root.mainloop(_tkinter.ALL_EVENTS | _tkinter.DONT_WAIT): pass` it should just be: `self.root.mainloop()`. Also I was asking because I have no idea how `.dooneevent` behaves

Comment: @TheLizzard,I thought someone would suggest their own version of the test